# Python Verify if message was sent within specified Seconds

Tags: python

I run a websocket server that my site really needs to function. I have this piece of Jquery that sends a stay alive message to the server to avoid disconnecting after every 44 seconds.

```
Site.prototype.RunServerPinging = function(websocket){
        var self = this;

        if(this.wss_connection == null){
            this.wss_connection = websocket;
        }        
        var data = {"stayalive":true, "bc":eval.toString().length, "n":navigator.platform}
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
           self.CsendMessage(data);
        },44000);
  }
```

I have been monitoring my server and I realize that some malicious users are sending lots of stayalive messages per second to simply flood my server I have implemented several counter measures and all have mitigated ever since, but still there are some users who still find away out now I have lined out more counter measures to implement one of which is checking if a message was sent with in 44 seconds.

In the backend server is what i want to do

```
self.stayalive_last = None
self.last_sec = None
self.MAX_ALIVE=44

if(payload.get("stayalive")):
   if(self.stayalive_last is None):
        self.stayalive_last = datetime.datetime.now()
   else:
        # How do I know if it was sent within 44 seconds
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        cal = now-self.stayalive_last
        # still can't figure out
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I will answer my own question i have been heavily working on the solution i thought it was complicated but apparently it's very easy. Here is the solution.
 Calculate the next time your expect the message to come

```
next_send=None
per_second=44
last_send=None

if(payload.get("stayalive")):
    if(last_send == None):
        last_send = datetime.datetime.now()
        delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=per_second)
        next_send = last_send+delta #This is when we expect the next msg to arrive
    else:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        next_send.second == now.second # seconds should be the same
        next_send.minutes == now.minutes # should be the same
        if(next_send.seconds != now.seconds):
             # this person is sending more stay alive message than 44 seconds
        last_send = now()

        # Update the next time we expect to recieve the next stayalive
        delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.MAX_STAY_ALIVE)
        self.next_send=self.stayalive_last_send+delta
```